# create executable android / apk game maker 2 is giving error ,(i use android studio)

Tags: android

the erro: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'W:\com.company.game\build.gradle' line: 62
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':com.company.game'.

> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 3s

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe DONE (1)
C:\Windows\system32\subst.exe /d W:

C:\Windows\system32\subst.exe DONE (0)
Error : Build Failed
Igor complete.